# Mock ActivatedRoute object in Angular2

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm using activated route to listen route data changes:

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.model.load(params['id']);
});
```

In my unit test I want to mock this part `this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe` to provide test data:

```
mockActivatedRoute.params = jasmine.createSpy('mockActivatedRoute.params')
  .and
  .returnValue(Observable.of(<Params>{id: 1}));
```

But I'm getting an error:

> Type 'Spy' is not assignable to type 'Observable'. Property
>   '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Spy'

What does this error mean? I'm using similar arrroach for other observers and everething works fine, but only this place.

Comment: You could stub `ActivatedRoute` instead. In your unit test, pass a stub instead of the actual `ActivatedRoute` class. Create a `params` property on your stub that returns an observable of the value you want.

Comment: Staying with your syntax, I think it should be `jasmine.createSpy('params')`.

Comment: @AngularFrance, it's just spy name. Yes, I can pass stub, but i need more code then to spy other parts of this objects. In my case better to use actual.

Comment: What I mean is, the main interest of a spy is to know whether a method is called, how many times, which arguments it received... In your case, all this is not important, you just want to return a custom observable. So why don't you store an observable in the `params` method **without** using a spy? I.e. `mockActivatedRoute.params = Observable.of(...)`

Comment: Yes, I had this solution before. But it's workaround for my case as I need clearing spies, check call count, etc. But anyway - thanks.

Comment: OK got it. How about you try to spy on the `subscribe` method instead of the `params` property? I'll post an answer with the code I have in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you try to spy on the `params.subscribe()` method instead of the `params` property?

Something along the lines of:

```ts
// This code might need some adjustments...
class MockActivatedRoute {
  params = {
    subscribe: jasmine.createSpy('subscribe')
     .and
     .returnValue(Observable.of(<Params>{id: 1}))
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems this creates incorrect object. You need to call `mockActivatedRoute.params.subscribe.subscribe`. Right?

Comment: No, you call the usual `activatedRoute.params.subscribe()`. The `createSpy()` method **replaces** the original method, it doesn't suffix it.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this can help someone like me. Adding to [AngularChef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42022504/6447736), I had a chain like this:

```
// component.ts
this.route.paramMap
    .flatMap((paramMap: Params) => {
        return paramMap.params['userId'];
    })
    .flatMap((userId: string) => {
        ...
    }
    .subscribe(whatever)...
```

And I couldn't mock it right from the module declaration because I need to test the component's response to different `userId`s coming from `paramMap`.

So just spying on the `flatMap` call from `route.paramMap` saved me a lot of lines.

```
// component.spec.ts
import { of } from 'rxjs';
//...
let route: ActivatedRoute;
// ...
route = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);
spyRoute = spyOn(route.paramMap, 'flatMap').and.returnValue(
   of(profileId), // notice this is just the string the next chain asks for
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested working in Angular 4

```
import { ActivatedRoute }                   from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }                       from 'rxjs/Rx';

...

class MockActivatedRoute extends ActivatedRoute {
  public params = Observable.of({id: 123});
}

...

describe('MyTest', () => {
  ...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      ...

      providers: [ { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: new MockActivatedRoute() } ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Still same here, no provider for ActivatedRouter