# Angular 2 how do I test a component that uses router

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am trying to write some tests for a component that calls `router.navigate()` and I'm stuck on errors with declaring the routes. I've read a lot of things and tried all of them but they all lead to some error or another. I am using Angular 4.0.0.

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private router: Router,
    private storageService: StorageService
  ) { ... }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  private login(formData: any): void {
    const credentials: any = {
      email: formData.controls.email.value,
      password: formData.controls.password.value
    };
    this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe(res => {
      this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
        if (params.returnUrl) {
          this.router.navigate([params.returnUrl]);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
        }
      });
    }, error => { ... });
  }
}
```

**Test:**

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: any;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: AuthService,
        useClass: MockAuthService
      }, {
        provide: JwtService,
        useClass: MockJwtService
      }, {
        provide: StorageService,
        useClass: MockStorageService
      }],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  describe('login', () => {
    it('should call router.navigate with the dashboard route if the login is successful', () => {
      spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');
      component.authService.login.and.returnValue(Observable.of({ access_token: 'fake_token' }));
      component.login(component.loginForm);
      expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
    });
  });
});
```

This all gives me the following error:

> zone.js:569 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard'

So from there I looked into adding the route with `withRoutes`. I don't like that I need to include the `DashboardComponent` since it seems like there should be some mocked/blank component available for this especially since I don't want to actually navigate and load another route but I couldn't find anything like that:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{
      path: 'dashboard',
      component: DashboardComponent
    }])
  ],
  ...
})
.compileComponents();
```

However that just give me a new error:

> Component DashboardComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.

So I thought that maybe I needed to declare the `DashboardComponent`, so I added it to the declarations array:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ LoginComponent, DashboardComponent ],
  ..
})
.compileComponents();
```

However that just lead to yet another error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DashboardComponent'

At this point it seems like there must be a simpler way to do this as it's a very common scenario but I've tried everything others say they used and everything just leads further down this rabbit hole.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution turned out to be really simple...

Simply adding the RouterTestingModule was almost there, only I needed to spy on router.navigate in all tests to prevent them from trying to actually navigate to another route.

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: any;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [
        SharedModule,
        RouterTestingModule   // This provides the mock router, location and routerLink
      ],
      providers: [{
        provide: AuthService,
        useClass: MockAuthService
      }, {
        provide: JwtService,
        useClass: MockJwtService
      }, {
        provide: StorageService,
        useClass: MockStorageService
      }],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');    // This prevents every test from calling the real router.navigate which means I don't need to add routes to RouterTestingModule
  });

  describe('login', () => {
    it('should call router.navigate with the dashboard route if the login is successful', () => {
      spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');
      component.authService.login.and.returnValue(Observable.of({ access_token: 'fake_token' }));
      component.login(component.loginForm);
      expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: How were you able to access `component.router`?  I don't have access to it without making the DI of Router in my component public.  Otherwise, thanks for pointing out RouterTestModule :)

Comment: By default the CLI types the component to the current component. i.e. `let component: LoginComponent;`. I'm not sure why they do this because it causes issues and prevents access to private variables & methods. Changing it to type any resolves this issue. `let component: any;` It's a pain because you can't change the template and have to make this change in every spec.

Comment: That works thanks.  I used a slight variation on your solution that's only difference is what is passed to the injector.  I posted it as a solution in case it helps, and only because code in comments is confusing.  Using this there is no need to change your spec to use `let component: any;`

Answer (score 2):

I found a slightly different solution then @efarley, which takes his answer and changes what the injector is provided.  Thought I'd add this in as well in case it helps anyone.  I used the Angular CLI so the spec is setup with the default blueprint for a test, and I've removed bits for brevity.

```
// NOTE: Other required test imports removed for brevity so this snippet
// only represents the minimum viable code required to test a route
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      providers: []
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    de = fixture.debugElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('form submission login and navigating to the dashboard', () => {
    el = de.nativeElement.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');

    // **ONLY** difference between the solutions is what is passed to the injector
    spyOn(de.injector.get(Router), 'navigate');
    el.click();

    expect(de.injector.get(Router).navigate)
      .toHaveBeenCalledWith(['dashboard']);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
spyOn(component.router, 'navigate');
```

You can't do this because the real `Router` need a bunch of other things to be configured in order to work. You should just create a mock of the `Router` that doesn't require anything.

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: Router,
    useValue: { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }
  }
]
```

Now you can do

```
expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
```

But the other problem is that you can call it synchronously. In side your `login` method, you have two different levels of asynchronous calls

```
this.authService.login(credentials).subscribe(res => {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
```

So you need to wait for these to complete. You could just use `fakeAsync` and `tick`

```
it('..', fakeAsync(() => {
  ..login()
  tick()
  expect(component.router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/dashboard']);
}))
```

I'm not quite sure how it would work in this case as you have two levels of asynchronous calls. I'm not sure if the `tick()` will just wait one turn or if it will also capture the second asynchronous call also. If it doesn't work, you can try to call `tick` again or call tick with a delay `tick(someMilliseconds)`

Comment: I've already tried this as I use the mockRouter method in a number of other tests. It seems since I use the activatedRoute in this component it exponentially complicates things. If I switch to a mockRouter I get an error that  there is no provider for  `ActivatedRoute`, I mock that and I get an error that there is no provider for `LocationStrategy`  and again I'm spiraling down a rabbits hole that I shouldn't need to go down.

Comment: You're probably bot mocking it right. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42022504/2587435

Comment: That's slightly different than what I'm doing but results in the same `LocationStrategy` error.

Comment: There should be no reason to get that error if you are configuring everything correctly. You're using mocks. The mocks don't need LocationStrategy. Somehow you are still trying to use the real ones

Comment: I agree but something in the app seems to require LocationStrategy even when the router and activatedRoute are mocked. This is likely why the devs recommend using RouterTestingModule which includes LocationStrategy

Comment: So after some more testing I found 1 line in my template that seems to be the issue. If I remove it everything works, if I leave it I get the error that LocationStrategy isn't provided. `<a [routerLink]='["/forgot-password"]'>Forgot Password?</a>` so it looks like the issue is `routerLink`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RouterTestingModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/testing/index/RouterTestingModule-class.html). The test guide has information [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#routed-component).

Comment: Did you not look at the code at all? I have been using it this entire time.

Comment: Please actually read more than the title before down voting a question and providing the same solution the OP is already using.

Comment: Also the link you provided for the guide doesn't even go to any information in regard to RouterTestingModule and instead recommends just creating a stub for router which has it's own issues.